# Making SQL query with multiple where conditions and variables more efficient

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which does get the results I require but is incredibly slow and surely there must be a better way of doing this as I would need to run this regularly.

Each where clause has two variables which will always be the same number but I need to use this with 50+ BigIDs, the example shows 3 but I would do it for BigID 1 to 50+.

I am unsure how to make this shorter because of the two variables (one of which being in a subquery) and group by which is required.
Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
 SELECT BigID,count(LittleID)
      FROM Table1
      where ( (BigID=1 and LittleID not in (SELECT LittleID FROM Table2 where BigID=1)) or
              (BigID=2 and LittleID not in (SELECT LittleID FROM Table2 where BigID=2)) or
              (BigID=3 and LittleID not in (SELECT LittleID FROM Table2 where BigID=3)) )
      group by BigID
```

Comment: Table definitions please. (So we know if LittleID and BigID exist in one or both tables...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
  SELECT t1.BigID, count(t1.LittleID)
  FROM Table1 t1
  WHERE t1.BigID IN (1, 2, 3) and
        t1.LittleID not in (SELECT t2.LittleID
                            FROM Table2 t2
                            WHERE t2.BigID = t1.BigId
                           )
  GROUP BY t1.BigID
```

Comment: It is generally better to construct a query that uses `NOT EXISTS` than one with `NOT IN` because of possible side-effects regarding `NULL` values. That probably doesn't play in this instance, but I prefer to stick with the construction that has the least side-effects. Otherwise performance is usually identical.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.BigID, COUNT(t1.LittleID)
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.LittleID = t2.LittleID AND t1.BigID = t2.BigID
WHERE t1.BigID IN (1, 2, 3)
    AND t2.LittleID IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.BigID
```

Comment: It is generally more efficient to drop the `LEFT JOIN`, and use a `NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table2 AS t2 WHERE t1.LittleID = t2.LittleID AND t1.BigID = t2.BigID)` in the `WHERE` clause. [Reference](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: @TT good note... in this case we can get `SEMI LEFT JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Table1.BigID,
       COUNT(Table1.LittleID)
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.LittleID = Table2.LittleID
    AND Table1.BigID = Table2.BigID
WHERE Table2.LittleID IS NULL
    AND Table1.BigID IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY Table1.BigID
```